# why does scanf_s cause Compiler Error on OnlineJudge?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I use **scanf_s** to input data.
It causes compiler error on OnlineJudge, while **scanf** can pass the test.
I've included **cstdio**.
Is **scanf_s** included in other STLs?

Comment: `scanf_s` is a microsoft extension; it is not standard C.

Comment: Most of the times I've seen questions here about the `XXX_s` functions, the problem is that the poster didn't give it the extra argument, they tried to call it like the original `XXX` function.

Comment: @GovindParmar actually scanf_s is in the C11 standard as part of an optional appendix. Doesn't look it like it's in C++, though. User, have you considered using `std::cin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Govind Parmar stated in his comment, [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/w40768et.aspx) is a Microsoft extension. [OnlineJudge](https://uva.onlinejudge.org) uses GNU C++ compilers, and thus, using Microsoft extensions will not work.

Helpful note: if you'd like to test your code on a standard compiler before submitting, there are several available online, such as [ideone](http://ideone.com/).